# Elm Effects Mapped to Nested Component

Tags: javascript, signals, rxjs, frp, elm

In this [example (RandomGifPair)](https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial/tree/master/examples/6), how is the update corresponding to NewGif actually wired to execute after the parent component fires `RandomGif.update act model.left`? It seems like the `RandomGif.update NewGif maybeUrl` needs to be manually fired somewhere. To be a little more explicit, RandomGifPair fires its Left update action and gets back a model / effect pair by manually calling RandomGif's update function. The returned effect is executed through the `Effects.map Left fx`, and that goes on to the getRandomGif function in RandomGif

```
getRandomGif : String -> Effects Action
getRandomGif topic =
  Http.get decodeUrl (randomUrl topic)
    |> Task.toMaybe
    |> Task.map NewGif
    |> Effects.task
```

which, as far as I understand it, will go on to fire the NewGif action which, due to the Effects.map, is now also tagged with Left. The only part of the picture I'm missing is how this action is kept within the scope of RandomGif and the action corresponding to the NewGif case of this update actually fired:

```
update : Action -> Model -> (Model, Effects Action)
update action model =
  case action of
    RequestMore ->
      (model, getRandomGif model.topic)

    NewGif maybeUrl ->
      ( Model model.topic (Maybe.withDefault model.gifUrl maybeUrl)
      , Effects.none
      )
```

when Main.elm only has the update function from RandomGifPair and thus has no case for NewGif.

I'm sure the answer lies in specific details of ports, Effects.map, forwardTo or Tasks that I'm missing.

For reference, [here is an attempt to solve the problem in javascript](https://github.com/low-ghost/react-rx-elm-architecture/blob/master/src/RandomGifPair.js) that contains an entry in the upper update function for NewGif and manually calls RandomGif.update inside of it. Probably not the best way to try to understand elm...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All actions come in to your top-level update function. There's no way to scope actions to a sub-update function - they always come in at the top. So, most programs will manually route actions down to the lower update functions. That's what's happening here. All of the actions must go into `RandomGifPair.update`, and it's up to that function to a) call sub functions and b) store the results in the right spot in the state. It can be surprisingly cumbersome.

[Here's the specific point in `RandomGifPair.update` that does the routing](https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial/blob/effffbe550f53d1e87835338d586fd8161ab12e3/examples/6/RandomGifPair.elm#L42).

Line 42 says "oh this is a `Left` action? Give me the `act` that's inside of there. NOW you have your desired `NewGif` or `RequestMore` stored in `act`, *and* you know that it was bound for the left one. Line 44 calls the lower update function, which knows how to handle that. Line 46 stores the result of the lower update function in the model (by recreating the whole model with the new left and re-using the old right).

This is all obscured by the boilerplate around Effects. If you can understand how the actions flow first, then go back and apply the same logic to the Effects, I think that'll become clearer.

Comment: Oh, I might be getting it. Let me ask this: so Left on line 42 handles both the RequestMore _and_ NewGif actions individually and calls the lower update for both actions? Surprisingly simple actually. So RequestMore is initially fired as a left action which eventually fires NewGif and both are handled by the Left case with the update being action agnostic, if that makes sense.

Comment: I'm going to go with, yep thats the case here. Very straightforward, just easy to get lost in the assumed complexity of the ports/Effects architecture. Thanks for walking me through it

Comment: A big a-ha moment for me was realizing that things like `Left` are actually functions. Sounds like you got it!

Answer (score 0):

I may be a little late to the party here, but effects can easily be mapped.

Take as follows:

```
type alias ChildModel = { number : Int }

type alias Model = { firstChild : ChildModel }


type ChildMsg = One | Two | Three

type Msg Nothing | ChildMsg1 ChildMsg


childUpdate : ChildMsg -> ChildModel -> (ChildModel, Cmd ChildMsg)
childUpdate msg model =
  case msg of
    One -> { model | number = model.number + 1 }
    Two -> { model | number = model.number + 2 }
    Three -> { model | number = model.number + 3 }

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Msg)
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Nothing -> (model, Cmd.none)
    ChildMsg1 mesg -> -- heres where the update is mapped
      let
        (childModel, childMsg) = childUpdate mesg model.firstChild
      in
        ( { model | firstChild = childModel }, Cmd.map ChildMsg1 childMsg)
```

Cmd.map maps a Top level Msg to a nested component. Think snake eating its own tail.